# add new plot to existing figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a script with some plots ( see example code). After some other things i want to add a new plot to an existing one. But when i try that it add the plot by the last created figure(now fig2).
I can't figure out how to change that...

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

n = 10
x1 = np.arange(n)
y1 = np.arange(n)    

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x1,y1)
fig1.show()

x2 = np.arange(10)
y2 = n/x2

# add new data and create new figure
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
ax2.plot(x2,y2)
fig2.show()

# do something with data to compare with new data
y1_geq = y1 >= y2
y1_a = y1**2
ax1.plot(y1_geq.nonzero()[0],y1[y1_geq],'ro')
fig1.canvas.draw
```

Answer (score 11):

Since your code is not runnable without errors I'll provide a sample snippet showing how to plot several data in same graph/diagram:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xvals = [i for i in range(0, 10)]
yvals1 = [i**2 for i in range(0, 10)]
yvals2 = [i**3 for i in range(0, 10)]

f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(xvals, yvals1)
ax.plot(xvals, yvals2)
```

So the basic idea is to call `ax.plot()` for all datasets you need to plot into the same plot.

Comment: I have no errors on my script...
And it is no answer on my question. i have still a second figure and i cant still not add a new plot to the first figure.

Comment: That's not correct. E.g. `x1` and `y2` are undefined in your snippet.

Comment: You need to adapt my example to your needs. This is not only copy-and-paste but more likely a general approach on how to plot different data in the same plot. So my code example stands on its own. In addition to that providing runnable code definitely is _your task_ as described in [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In addition, if you are looking for realtime plotting e.g. for sensors, you can find the following example: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/graph-sensor-data-with-python-and-matplotlib/update-a-graph-in-real-time

The basic idea is to keep a data list and use the matplotlib.animation module.